# How to flag a post as off-topic because: Issues found in existing modules/themes

Tags: support

How do I flag posts as being off topic due to *Issues found in existing modules/themes*.

When I go to flag > it should be closed for another reason... > off-topic because... I see:

- Questions on programming, PHP, SQL, etc...
- This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced...
- This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network ...

But none of these are the correct reason.

[This post](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2477/custom-off-topic-reasons-for-drupal-anwers) suggests lots of other reason are going to be added.

Is this happening?

Comment: These aren't automatically off topic.  A pure bug report is off topic.  Asking for a workaround for an established bug is on-topic.  A problem with a module may or may not be off-topic (we handle this case-by-case).

Comment: Ok - if in doubt I'll just leave it alone.

Comment: Once you hit 3k, you can cast close votes on these types of questions.  If enough people agree with you, then the question will be closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. You can only flag with specific reasons provided.

Custom reasons are only available for people with [cast close and reopen votes](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions) privilege.

It is a design decision to prevent too much bad creativity from the people with too low reputation. Reputation measures (roughly) how much community trusts you, and it takes quite some (3000) trust to allow closing because you *feel* it's off-topic. Sometime question is about issue in existing module, but OP actively tries to fix it and simply stuck at some point. Or is looking for alternative modules to achieve the same goal. These can be pretty OK - it's a delicate matter that requires trust (reputation).

If you are afraid people allowed to vote will miss question that should be closed, you may flag for diamond moderator's attention. But if it sits on the front page, just leave it be.

For the reasons from question you linked: They were never implemented. Don't know why. We use them as a rough guideline for freeform reason, and sadly that's all for now.

Comment: Ah ha, I see. Cool - will do.